# How to send ajax to the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using pure js to send ajax request to other .php page, I'm really new to ajax concept so I don't know a lot.
I've seen jQuery ajax, but I prefer learning the pure js ajax so I can understand how ajax works.

I need to send ajax to the same page instead of sending it to another page to process the data. is it possible to do that? and How?

My Index page:

```
<div id="response"></div>
    <form method="post" id="myForm">
        <span>Username: </span>
        <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span>Age: </span>
        <input type="number" name="age" id="age">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

my php code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['uname']) && isset($_GET['age'])) {
        $name = trim(strip_tags($_GET['uname'])); $age = trim(strip_tags($_GET['age']));
        echo !empty($name) && !empty($age) ?
            '<p style="color:green">Hello: '.$name.' You\'re '.$age.' Years Old :D</p>' :
            '<p style="color:red">Please Write your Name and Your Age</p>';
    }
```

my ajax code:

```
    window.onload = function() {
    var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
    myForm.onsubmit = function() {
        // Create the object from XMLHttpRequest 
        var xhttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new window.XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"),
                uname = document.getElementById('uname').value,
                age = document.getElementById('age').value,
                result = document.getElementById('response'),
                url = 'ajax-thing.php?uname='+uname+'&age='+age;
        xhttp.onload = function() {
            result.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        };
        xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
        xhttp.send();
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: First, jquery is not a requirement for success in your case.  Second, can you explain why you *need* to send the ajax request to the same page?  It seems to me that you would have to write condition statements to stop the original form and other content from being passed back in the responseText.  If it can be done, it will be lighter and cleaner to point ajax to a separate file for handling.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax-thing.php',
            data: "uname="+uname+"&age="+age,
            success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); // it will show the result in console
            }
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: I think I mentioned that I'm using pure JS for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

That is possible. On server you only need verify ajax request (When you make a request using ajax, a header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` will be attached to request). If you want make that easier, you can add new params to url, to notice server know this is an ajax request, something like: `ajax-thing.php?uname='+uname+'&age='+age + '&ajax=1'`,  and return whatever you want if that is ajax request.

Comment: so I've to add (&ajax=1) to the end of the url?
I mean i don't want to send the ajax request to (ajax-thing.php) page, instead I want it to be send to the same page (index.php).
Is that possible?

Comment: That is possible, This param just to tell with server know this request sent by Ajax and you can handle this request more easy. Ajax don't care your url is same page or not. So don't worry about that.

Comment: But I tried to send the request to the same page, and the result comes as the whole document, I mean it prints out the structure of the html document I have in that current page, Do you know what's the problem? have you ever tried to send the request to the same page before? and If you please have an example of how I can do it, I'd appreciate your help.. Thanks.

Comment: No, problem with you. But you need handle for ajax request. You could try [this code](https://gist.github.com/dotuancd/1fa7b7e999d876373b62d5f00af40972).

Comment: Contact with me if you need more supporting: [My Facebook](https://fb.com/dotuancd)